# Unable to do an insert using datasnap client

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I am experimenting with datasnap (never used it before) and have run into a strange issue.
Maybe I am doing it wrong, I don't know.
I have placed a Clientdataset3 on my form. Linked it to SQLConnection1 (on the same form)
Which connects to datasnap server.
I have also linked the Clientdataset3 to the datasetprovider (which allows command text) on the server side that
Is linked to the table I want to insert into. However when I run:

```
procedure TForm3.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
clientdataset3.CommandText:='insert into "MY_TABLE" (twit) values (:A)';
clientdataset3.Params.ParamByName('A').AsString := cxmemo1.Lines.Text;
clientdataset3.Execute;
end;
```

I get "Remote error: no such table:insert"

What am I doing wrong ? Database is SQLite via DBX, using XE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are populating your CDS using a SELECT statement, you don't need to go through the exercise of sending a bespoke INSERT statement.

You should be able to just call

```
ClientDataSet3.Insert;
// populate fields here
ClientDataSet3.Post;
```

Followed by a call to ClientDataSet3.ApplyUpdates.

Similarly, you can do a DELETE just by calling ClientDataSet3.Delete.

The construction of necessary INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements is handled by the CDS's provider.  However I'm not intending to suggest that you *can't* do an INSERT the way you're trying - it should work fine.

I can't tell what's going wrong with your INSERT from here, so instead, here's some code which works for me (including CREATE TABLE, etc statements) so you can maybe "spot the difference."  I'm using XE6 on Win7 64-bit and v.3.8.5.0 of sqlite3.dll dated June 4, 2014.

The sample code provides 3 ways (all checked and working) of doing an insert, two using custom INSERT statements and the third using the default insert behaviour of a CDS, which can be invoked in code (CDS1.Insert) and by clicking the '+' button on the DBNavigator.  The default CDS insert behaviour requires special handling: Although the ID column on the server is defined as Autoinc, getting the autoinc value while doing a CDS Insert is problematic, so the code uses the method described here:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20847

of generating a temporary, negative, ID value which is replaced during the CDS ApplyUpdates process.  Note from the DFM that the measure referred to in the Errata section of the link regarding the ProviderFlags in the SqlQuery ID field is necessary because the ID column value on the server is a 64-bit Integer.

```
type
  TDataOperation = (doCreateTable, doDropTable, doInsert, doInsertUsingParams, doSelect);

TForm3 = class(TForm)
[...]
{ private declarations }
  ID : Int64;
  function NextID : Int64;
[...]
end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  scCreateTable = 'CREATE TABLE [MATable2] ([ID] INTEGER NOT NULL '
    + #13#10 + 'PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  [AName] VARCHAR(20), '
    + #13#10 + '  [AMemo] MEMO)';

  scDropTable =
    'DROP TABLE [MATable2]';

  scInsert1 =
    'INSERT INTO [MATable2] (AName, AMemo) VALUES(''a'', ''A memo'')';

  scSelect =
    'SELECT * FROM [MATable2]';

  scInsertUsingParams =
    'INSERT INTO [MATable2] (AName, AMemo) VALUES(:AName, :AMemo)';

procedure TForm3.PerformTableOperation(Operation : TDataOperation);
var
  Param : TParam;
begin
  if {(Operation in [toCreate, toDrop]) and} CDS1.Active then
    CDS1.Close;
  case Operation of
    doCreateTable : begin
      CDS1.CommandText := scCreateTable;
      CDS1.Execute;
      PerformTableOperation(doSelect);
    end;
    doDropTable : begin
      CDS1.CommandText := scDropTable;
      CDS1.Execute;
    end;
    doSelect : begin
      CDS1.CommandText := scSelect;
      CDS1.Open;
    end;
    doInsert : begin
      CDS1.CommandText := scInsert1;
      CDS1.Execute;
      PerformTableOperation(doSelect);
    end;
    doInsertUsingParams : begin

      CDS1.CommandText := scInsertUsingParams;
//      CDS1.FetchParams;
      CDS1.Params.ParamByName('AName').AsString:= 'bcdef';
      CDS1.Params.ParamByName('AMemo').AsString := 'memo b';
      CDS1.Execute;
      CDS1.Params.Clear;

      PerformTableOperation(doSelect);
    end;
  end;
  if CDS1.Active then  // it won't be  after a toDrop
    CDS1.ApplyUpdates(-1);
end;


procedure TForm3.OpenConnection;
begin
 SqlConnection1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm3.btnCreateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PerformTableOperation(doCreateTable);
end;

[etc ...]

procedure TForm3.btnReopenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CDS1.Close;
  PerformTableOperation(doSelect);
end;

procedure TForm3.btnSelectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PerformTableOperation(doSelect);
end;

procedure TForm3.CDS1AfterDelete(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  CDS1.ApplyUpdates(-1);
end;

procedure TForm3.CDS1AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  CDS1.ApplyUpdates(-1);
end;

procedure TForm3.CDS1NewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  CDS1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger := NextID;
end;

function TForm3.NextID: Int64;
begin
  Dec(ID);
  Result := ID;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OpenConnection;
end;

end.
```

And here's a partial DFM to minimize the need for guessing how my DB components are set up.

```
object Form3: TForm3
[...]
  object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 456
    Height = 193
    DataSource = DataSource1
    TabOrder = 0
    TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
    TitleFont.Height = -11
    TitleFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    TitleFont.Style = []
    Columns = <
      item
        Expanded = False
        FieldName = 'ID'
        Visible = True
      end
      item
        Expanded = False
        FieldName = 'AName'
        Visible = True
      end
      item
        Expanded = False
        FieldName = 'AMemo'
        Visible = True
      end>
  end
  [...]
  object DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator
    Left = 16
    Top = 216
    Width = 240
    Height = 25
    DataSource = DataSource1
    TabOrder = 6
  end
  object DBMemo1: TDBMemo
    Left = 207
    Top = 259
    Width = 185
    Height = 74
    DataField = 'AMemo'
    DataSource = DataSource1
    TabOrder = 7
  end
  object DBEdit1: TDBEdit
    Left = 24
    Top = 264
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    DataField = 'AName'
    DataSource = DataSource1
    TabOrder = 8
  end
  object SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection
    ConnectionName = 'SQLITECONNECTION'
    DriverName = 'Sqlite'
    LoginPrompt = False
    Params.Strings = (
      'DriverName=Sqlite'
      'Database=D:\delphi\xe6\sqlite\matestdb.sqlite')
    Connected = True
    Left = 40
    Top = 16
  end
  object SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery
    MaxBlobSize = 1
    Params = <>
    SQL.Strings = (
      'select * from [matable2]')
    SQLConnection = SQLConnection1
    Left = 128
    Top = 16
    object SQLQuery1ID: TLargeintField
      FieldName = 'ID'
      ProviderFlags = [pfInWhere, pfInKey]
    end
    object SQLQuery1AName: TWideStringField
      FieldName = 'AName'
    end
    object SQLQuery1AMemo: TWideMemoField
      FieldName = 'AMemo'
      BlobType = ftWideMemo
      Size = 1
    end
  end
  object DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider
    DataSet = SQLQuery1
    Options = [poAllowCommandText, poUseQuoteChar]
    UpdateMode = upWhereKeyOnly
    Left = 216
    Top = 16
  end
  object CDS1: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    CommandText = 'select * from MATable2'
    Params = <>
    ProviderName = 'DataSetProvider1'
    BeforeInsert = CDS1BeforeInsert
    AfterInsert = CDS1AfterInsert
    BeforePost = CDS1BeforePost
    AfterPost = CDS1AfterPost
    AfterDelete = CDS1AfterDelete
    OnNewRecord = CDS1NewRecord
    AfterApplyUpdates = CDS1AfterApplyUpdates
    Left = 288
    Top = 16
    object CDS1ID: TLargeintField
      FieldName = 'ID'
    end
    object CDS1AName: TWideStringField
      FieldName = 'AName'
    end
    object CDS1AMemo: TWideMemoField
      FieldName = 'AMemo'
      BlobType = ftWideMemo
      Size = 1
    end
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    DataSet = CDS1
    Left = 344
    Top = 16
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure I understand you right... I am not selecting but running a kind of insert query.

Comment: That's quite an unusual thing to do.  If I wanted to do such an insert, I would use 'SELECT * from MY_TABLE WHERE 1=2' and leave the rest to the CDS + its provider.  Try it.  BTW, you're not trying to insert more than one column value into the A parameter, are you?  I wasn't quite sure whether 'twit' is meant to be a column name or what.

Comment: actually I was going to insert more values but I was just doing one for a start to see if it works. twit is a field in my database (memo). How exactly do you insert into a table that is on server side from the client?

Comment: I'd use a dummy SELECT statement like the one I suggested - that way the provider + CDS can get as much metadata as poss, and then just .Open the CDS.  It will start with zero rows, but won't care.  I wouldn't expect trying to insert a row with only a Memo field to work, whether using a CDS or no - there is nothing the (Delphi) datasets can use as a key.  But I could be wrong on that ...

Comment: @user763539:  Are you making any progress with this or still stuck?

Comment: @ MartynA - no marty,sorry....all examples teach you how to construct a datasnap server but non of them how to insert data.It seems I am missing a fundamental principle on how the thing functions (insert). So please tell me how do you actually insert the data? My dataset is linked to the dataprovider (the table on the server) so a simple query (thats why I am doing a single insert) from clientdataset should work. Or am I missing something ? Delphi is XE6 using DBX.

Comment: "Although the ID column on the server is defined as Autoinc, getting the autoinc value while doing a CDS Insert is problematic,"  - I've noticed this. Thank you.